# JavaMail to send email through vps, require NO authentication, but get AuthenticationFailedException - why?

Tags: java, email, authentication, smtp, jakarta-mail

I originally setup my site to use my local ISP to send email through my site. I would like to change this, and start sending email through my VPS. According to the online documentation (from my vps provider) I have "POP before SMTP authentication". So then, I do not require authentication nor do I require a secure connection at this time.

I changed a few things in the code I used for sending email through my local ISP. Here's what I have :

```
Transport t = null; 
   try {
    String Username = "mrsmith@mydomain.com";
    String Password = "somepassword";

        InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("mrsmith@mydomain.com", "Bob Smith");                        

    Properties props = new Properties();                                    

   //commented out, since I don't want to use authentication
   //props.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");           

   props.put("mail.pop3.host", "mydomain.com";
   props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mydomain.com");

   String protocol = "smtp";             
   Session ssn = Session.getInstance(props, null);
   ssn.setDebug(true);  

 t = ssn.getTransport(protocol);    

Store s = ssn.getStore();
s.connect();

  t.connect(SMTP,Username,Password);

//Create the message
Message msg = new MimeMessage(ssn);
msg.setFrom(from);
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setContent(body, "text/html");

t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
t.close();
s.close();
```

I contacted my vps provider and after following their instructions, in tweaking the code, I still get "Authentication Failed". This after a successful connection has been made to the host on port 25.

Can someone point out what it is I'm missing here?

## Editing to add additional information

After I added the store.connect("mailhost",Username,Password); statement to the code, I got further than ever before!

Here is some info that was printed to the tomcat prompt -

```
DEBUG : getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Sun Microsystems, Inc.]
POP3: connecting to host "mydomain.com", port 110, isSSL false
server ready
OK User name accepted, password please
Password somepassword
OK Mailbox open, 0 messages

DEBUG: geProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smpt.SMTPTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc.]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "mydomain.com", port 25, isSSL false 
220 mydomain.com ESMTP Sendmail 8.14.3/8.14.3; DEC 2010 29
DEBUG SMTP: connected to host "mydomain.com", port: 25
( a lot of additional debug information was here )
DEBUG SMTP: Attempt to authenticate
AUTH LOGIN
535 5.7.0 authentication failed
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
  at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
... continues with more 'at's.
```

**Do you see anything odd in this information? I don't quite understand why the authentication failed while the Pop3 was authenticated with the same username and password.**

Comment: What's in the mail log on your VPS?

Comment: Dec 28 15:48:40 motokarz saslauthd[20304]: do_auth         : auth failure: 
[user=mrsmith] [service=smtp] [realm=mydomain.com] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth 
error]

Do you know how I can disable SMTP authentication in my web application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POP before SMTP authentication basically means you need to be able to prove that you can fetch your mail using POP3 (using proper authentication) before you will be allowed to send mail using SMTP (without authentication).

Using the Java Mail API, you can do the authentication to the POP3 server like this :

```
Store store = ssn.getStore("pop3");
store.connect("mailhost", Username, Password);
```

You should execute these calls prior to connecting to the SMTP server, so before connecting to the SMTP server (without username and password) like this

```
t.connect();
```

make sure you connect to the store first.

In your snippet, you are still  authenticating against the smtp as you are providing a username/password.

Another option is to use Commons Email, that has built-in support for pop before smtp authentication. Check out the following method in http://commons.apache.org/email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/Email.html

```
email.setPopBeforeSMTP(true,popHost,popUsername,popPassword);
```

Using commons email, there's no need to do the pop plumbing in your code (connecting prior to sending).

Comment: I tried what you instructed - I put the code right before t.sendMessage() and after t.connect().... I'm still getting the same exception though...   Please note the changes I made, per your suggestion, in my original post above (look in code snippet please).

Comment: In your code, you're connecting to SMTP before you're authenticating through POP. t.connect(SMTP,Username,Password) already connects to the SMTP server, not the sendMessage()

Comment: Okay, made the changes, and now I'm getting a javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException with Invalid Protocol : null       I assume I'm missing something else, but what?

Comment: You're getting there ... I edited the answer. Did you try it with ssn.getStore("pop3") instead of ssn.getStore() ?

Comment: Thank you for continuing to assist me:) I just tried changing it to ssn.getStore("pop3") and I got the AuhenticationFailedException again. I then changed "pop3" to "POP3", just to try it, and then I got the "NoSuchProviderException : No provider for POP3".

Comment: Needs to be lower case. You are connecting to POP with a valid username/password right ? using store.connect("mailhost", Username, Password); And the pop3 settings are correct (including the port) ? And the AuhenticationFailedException is coming from SMTP, not from pop ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a valid Username/Password which I personally created for the email account. Hmm...uh-oh, NO I wasn't using store.connect("mailhost",Username,Password) for that particular method. I had it for Transport.connect, but not the Store object. I will make the appropriate changes now and try again. There isn't enough room in this 'comment' box to type out some additional info, so I'm going to post a 'reply' to my post with that information...will take me a few mins to get it all down.

Comment: Edit the question instead of posting an answer.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, deleted my answer and edited original post instead.

Comment: In your answer above, with regards to the snippet I appended, you said that I shouldn't be authenticating against the smtp...is that something I have control over? I was wondering where in my code I was doing that?

Comment: yes,instead of doing t.connect(SMTP,Username,Password), just to t.connect(). By providing a username password, you're effectively trying to authenticate against the smtp server.

Comment: Oh thank you so much! It is working successfully. I have a question. What does props.setProperites("mail.smtp.auth","true") do? Is that another way of authenticating on the smtp?

Comment: given the length of this one, perhaps this should be picked up in a seperate question :)

Comment: Your right:) Really, thanks again for all the help. I was completely lost on this problem, and I thank you for taking the time to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "mailserver.com");
Session s = Session.getInstance(props,null);

InternetAddress from = new InternetAddress("mail@mail.com");
InternetAddress to = new InternetAddress(recepeint@server.com");
```

For more information please visit:

http://www.itpian.com/Coding/314-SENDING-EMAILS-THROUGH-JAVAMAIL.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check if provider implementation(pop3.jar) is in your buildpath/classpath.